# Return a value from mui dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, material-ui, dialog

I have created a custom React hook to use MUI Dialog using React Context API. However, I need to return some value from Dialog, like if the OK button has been clicked. But I have some troubles.

Here is code snippet from context provider:

```
const showAlertDialog = (title: string, text?: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    setOpen(true);
    setTitle(title);
    setText(text);
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (value: boolean) => void) => {
      setActionCallback(resolve);
    });
  };

  const handleOKClick = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    actionCallback?.(true);
  };

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider value={{ showAlertDialog }}>
      {children}
      <DialogContainer
        title={title}
        open={open}
        text={text}
        onOK={handleOKClick}
      ></DialogContainer>
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useMuiDialog = () => {
  return useContext(DialogContext);
};
```

However when I call the await showAlertDialog form onClick handler, it immediately returns without waiting for promise to resolve/reject:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log('dialog');
    const answer = await showAlertDialog('test', 'test');
    console.log(answer);
  };
```

I am not getting something here, but I don't know what...

The whole example can be found on:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bk1d19?file=demo.tsx

Thank you

Comment: what is the solution then :D?

Comment: first of all I am not sure why do you need to store that resolve? If you still want it, you could put it inside an object and store the object for example.

Comment: I need to know the answer from client, ok or cancel....so I am awaiting on promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Giorgi Moniava for pointing me in right direction. Instead of setting callback directly, I have used function form of setState hook:

```
const showAlertDialog = (title: string, text?: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    setOpen(true);
    setTitle(title);
    setText(text);
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (value: boolean) => void) => {
      setActionCallback(() => resolve);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

What could be happening is this:

```
  setActionCallback(resolve);
```

You think you didn't invoke `resolve` here because you store it in state, but when you call set state in react *with a function*, react thinks you are using set state with updater function; from the docs:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to setState. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value.

So it probably immediately invoked the `resolve` function.

Answer (score -1):

hope you are doing well! I would do this in a very simple way, and it's by passing the setState from the Parent component of the dialog.

Let's say we have the Parent component named Parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

return <Dialog setValue={setValue}/>
```

In the dialog I would simply do:

```
const Dialog = ({setValue}) => {
const handleOk = () => setValue("OK");
const handleCancel = () => setValue("Cancel");

return ...
}
```

And like that you can read the value "Ok" or "Cancel" from the parent component.

PS: Of course you should add the setState of the opening and closing of the dialog.

Comment: Please see a complete example, I am using custom hooks here o programatically open a dialog.